# Prove what elements are in the set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

So I got the two sets:

$$ I = \left(-1,1+ \frac1n\right)    $$ 
$$ J = \left[0,1-\frac1n\right]$$

whereas $(a,b)= \{{x \in \mathbb R}: a<x<b\}$ 
and $ [a,b]= \{x \in \mathbb R: a  ≤ x ≤b\}$

And I have to find the elements of $$\bigcap\limits_{n\in\mathbb N}I $$ and $$
\bigcup\limits_{n\in\mathbb N}J $$

Now I would say that the intersection of I  is $\{{x \in \mathbb R}:-1<x≤1\}$
and that the union of J is $\{{x \in \mathbb R}:0≤x≤1\}$

Am I correct, and if so - how would you formally solve this? The way I did it was just thinking it through in my head but if I had to come up with a prove I might get stuck.

Comment: The first is correct. The second one no.

Comment: Hmm, I cant seem to find what I did wrong. I mean its obvious that 0 is the lower boundary, but as 1/n = 0 for a number n large enough, why doesnt it reach 1?

Comment: @mexeroser Can you really get $1$ to be in the union?

Comment: $1$ does not belong to the union.

Comment: @Stefan4024 I see. So you have to exclude it. This seemed very confusing to me, as I intuitively thought that both outer elements automatically get included as its a closed interval.

Comment: Here's the issue you're having. 1 is in the union if and only if it is an element of [0,1-1/n] for some natural number n. But for any particular n, it should be clear that 1 is not in fact an element of that set.

Comment: "that both outer elements automatically get included as its a closed interval"  Yes, but 1 is *not* one of the outer elements  and yes *all* the 1-1/n get included but the get "burried as 1- 1/1 < 1 -1/2 < 1-1/3 < ..... 1- 1/n < 1-1/(n+1) < ......   There *is* no other endpoint to be included.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: to check if some point $x$ belongs to $\bigcap I_n$ or $\bigcup J_n$ observe that

$$x\in\bigcap I_n\iff \forall n\in\Bbb N:x\in I_n$$

and

$$x\in\bigcup J_n\iff \exists n\in\Bbb N:x\in J_n$$

Check this for dubious points as $x=1$ or any other that you dont see clearly if belong or not to some set.

Answer (score 0):

How to formally solve:

Well, To be thoruogh.

If $x \le -1$ then $x \not \in (-1, 1+ 1/n)$ for any $n$ so $x \not \in \cap (-1, 1+ 1/n)$.

If $-1 < x \le 1$ then $-1 < x \le 1 < 1 + 1/n$ for all $n$ so $x \in \cap (-1, 1+ 1/n)$.

if $x > 1$ then $x - 1 > 0$ so there exists a natural number $n$ so that $x-1 > 1/n > 0$.  So $x \not \in (-1, 1+1/n)$ so $x \not \in \cap (-1, 1+ 1/n)$.

So $x \in \cap (-1, 1+ 1/n) \iff -1 < x \le 1$ so $\cap (-1, 1+ 1/n) = (-1, 1]$.

The second part similarly.  if $0 \le x < 1$ then $1 -x > 0$ so there exists a $n$ so the $1 - x > 1/n > 0$ so $0\le x < 1 - 1/n$ so $x \in [0, 1-1/n]$ so $x \in \cup [0,1-1/n]$ but if $x \ge 1$ then $x \ge 1 > 1-1/n$ for all $n$ so $x$ is not in union and obviously if $x < 0$ then $x$ is not in the union.